# When will future "departure_time" for "driving direction" be available?

Tags: google-maps

My company is looking for map API that supports driving route and time inquiries for future trips, e.g. getting a best route for a trip tomorrow at noon. A closer prediction would be use historical average traffic to generate such a route.

I thought Google Maps would have such capability, but it doesn't seem that they do, according to the description on their website:

"For driving directions: Google Maps API for Work customers can specify the departure_time to receive trip duration considering current traffic conditions. The departure_time must be set to within a few minutes of the current time."

So my question is: why Google is not doing general departure_time based inquiries at the moment? Is Google planning to offer the service in future? If so, when?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a feature request at Google Maps [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/)